# How to Convert XML to MessageElement[] Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services

Hi I am doing Integration with a webservice which takes in MessageElement[] and the sample input they have provided is given in XML format. Well am really confused how to convert the XML into MessageElement[].

The sample XML is :

```
'<DEBITS hasChanges="inserted" xmlns="">' .
'<DEBIT_ID>-1</DEBIT_ID>' .
'<EFFECTIVE_DATE>'.$FeeDate.'</EFFECTIVE_DATE>' .
'<DEBIT_AMOUNT>'. $Fee.'</DEBIT_AMOUNT>' .
'<MEMO><![CDATA['.$DEBIT_TYPE.']]></MEMO>' .
'<ACCOUNT_ID>'.$GCSAccountId .'</ACCOUNT_ID>' .
'<DEBIT_TYPE>'.$DEBIT_TYPE.'</DEBIT_TYPE>' .
'<DAY_OF_MONTH>'.$Feeday.'</DAY_OF_MONTH>' .
'<ACTIVE_FLAG>Y</ACTIVE_FLAG>' .
'<OCCURS_NUM>1</OCCURS_NUM>' .
'<CREATION_DATE></CREATION_DATE>' .
'<MODIFIED_DATE></MODIFIED_DATE>' .
'<MODIFIED_BY></MODIFIED_BY>' .
'<DEBIT_AUTHORIZED></DEBIT_AUTHORIZED>' .
'<DEBIT_AUTHORIZED_BY></DEBIT_AUTHORIZED_BY>' .
'<REMAINING_OCCURRENCES>0</REMAINING_OCCURRENCES></DEBITS>';
```

Just to add more context , the webservice proxy class that were generated using axis has a signature which accepts MessageElement[]

Comment: Well I have no Idea how to proceed on this. I am totally unware about the org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement class. Even representing a single element inot a messageElement will be really helpful fro example this line '<MEMO><![CDATA['.$DEBIT_TYPE.']]></MEMO>'

Comment: I suppose there is some documentation out there on the web about this class. What about these? Have you read them? Perhaps they even provide an example. @Avidev9

Comment: @11684 thanks for the reply... really never knew that!!

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. If you're using Axis, you should be able to use the web service code directly. Axis handles the translation to the required XML for you. Just create MessageElements like any other Java data structure and send them to the service in the appropriate request object.

Comment: Also: [Axis tutorial](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL).

Comment: @millimoose thanks. I used axis to generate the proxy classes but webservice class that was generated is having this signature only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well after going through lots of documents.
I guess I figured out how to handle the conversion.
Here is the method to convert the xml

```
public static MessageElement[] convertXMLStringtoMessageElement(String xmlString) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{
        MessageElement[] m = new MessageElement[1];
        Document XMLDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
        Element element = XMLDoc.getDocumentElement();
        m[0] = new MessageElement(element);
        return m;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand contrary comments about to use ordinary xml builders, but reverse from string are very useful in unit tests for soap clients, also for testing several error situations.